# Angular @Input value coming from?

Tags: angular

I have an angular @Input setter. And I'm not sure where its value coming from?

I assume this @Input value is coming from its parent. And I set a setter to its parent property. But failed, it not coming from its parent. But it is coming from a wrapper.

```
// attribute.component.html
<attribute-error [errors]="control.errors" [style.visibility]="(control.errors && (control.dirty || control.touched)) ? 'inherit' : 'hidden'"></attribute-error>
```

```
// attribute-error.component.ts
  @Input('errors') public set errors(inputValue: ErrorTypes) {
    this._errors = inputValue;
    this.hasErrors = inputValue ? !!Object.keys(inputValue).length : false;
```

call stack trace

```
// Wrapper_AttributeErrorComponent.check_errors
// SharedModule/AttributeErrorComponent/wrapper.ngFactory.js
// I cannot find this file in the project, where it is coming from
Wrapper_AttributeErrorComponent.prototype.check_errors = function(currValue,throwOnChange,forceUpdate) {
  var self = this;
  if ((forceUpdate || jit_checkBinding2(throwOnChange,self._expr_0,currValue))) {
    self._changed = true;
    self.context.errors = currValue;
```

Expect `errors` inject from parent component `attribute.component.html`

Comment: You dont need the public in typescript. Is is getting into the setter?

Comment: Post a **complete minimal** example reproducing the problem, as a stacjkblitz. There are way too many unknowns in what you posted to help.

Comment: Also, do not use input renaming (`@Input('errors')`). The file you said you couldn't find may be inside `dist` folder. It's the transpiled version.